# How to install Drupal in OpenShift Origin

Tags: openshift-origin

How to install Drupal on OpenShift Origin from console command.
 and deploy my website on it.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

using rhc :

```
rhc app create drupal php-5.3 mysql-5.1 cron
```